# Force two <div> to same size, but subtract one div with X pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I brought two `<div>` to the same height using Javascript:

```
var tallness = $("#first").height();
$("#second").height(tallness);
```

But how can i manage the `<div>` with the `id="second"` to be 20px shorter than the `id="first"`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe: $("#second").height(tallness-20);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to `substract` this value from `height` value.

```
$("#second").height(tallness-20);
```

```js
var tallness = $("#first").height();
$("#second").height(tallness-20);
console.log("First div height: "+ $("#first").height());
console.log("Second div height: "+ $("#second").height());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">
  first<BR>
  first<BR>
  first
</div>
<div id="second">
  second
  second
  second
</div>
```